# AKS an ACI Deployment with blob mount

Tags: azure-aks, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-container-instances

I have a use case wherein I need to refer to the input dataset in the ACI/AKS which is in a blob (same used for training model). I'm not able to find related resources in the Microsoft official documentation. If anyone suggests to me how to do it, that will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be supported in the near future, Running Python scripts on Azure with Azure Container Instances to connect the blob.
https://kohera.be/tutorials-2/running-python-scripts-on-azure-with-azure-container-instances/